# How to find the closed form solution for the multivariate recurrence?

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form

Recurrence relation:

```
f(n,k) = f(n-1,k) + f(n-1,k-1) + f(n-2,k-1)
```

Initial conditions:

```
f(n,0) = 1, f(n,1) = 2n, f(n,n) = 2  
f(n,k) = 0 for n < k
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the polynomials $p_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n f(n,k) x^k$.  Then the recurrence becomes
$p_{n}(x) = (x+1) p_{n-1}(x) + x p_{n-2}(x)$ with
$p_0(x)=1$ and $p_1(x) = 1+2x$.  The generating function is
$$ g(t,x) = \frac{1+tx}{1-(1+x)t - xt^2}$$
Hmm... seems to be [OEIS sequence A035607](https://oeis.org/A035607).