# Solve a 2 variable recurrence relation with 3 terms

Tags: recurrence-relations

$f(n,k) = f(n-1,k) + f(n-1,k-1) + f(n-2,k-1)$

$f(n,1) = 2n$

$f(1,k) = 2$ if $k = 1$

$f(1,k) = 0$ if $k\geq2$

$f(2,k) = 4$ if $k = 1$

$f(2,k) = 2$ if $k = 2$

$f(2,k) = 0$ if $k\geq3$

How to solve this 2-variable recurrence relation?

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2955806/how-to-find-the-closed-form-solution-for-the-multivariate-recurrence) is very similar.  So is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954299/solve-recurrence-relation)

Comment: Thank you so much Ross!!

Comment: If they allow you to answer your own question, the FAQ encourages that.  After a bit of time (2 days?) you can accept the answer.  In any case, if you make progress it will encourage people if you edit it into your question.